# Structure nested inside another structure as a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

So basically I am making a program that stores student information and the students scores both inside of structures.  I need help figuring out how to store values into the vector grades for each student, given some have 2-3 test scores each and all of the information is coming from an input file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Structures
struct Scores
{
    int id;
    string course = "";
    int credit;
    int score;
};

struct Person
{
    int id;
    string name = "";
    string phone = "";
    vector<Scores> grades;
};

// Function prototypes
void displayOne(vector<Person>, int);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    ifstream inputFile2;
    inputFile.open("StudentInfo.txt");
    inputFile2.open("StudentScores.txt");

    Scores tempScore;
    Person tempStudent;
    vector<Person> students;

    if (inputFile)
    {
        int value = 0;
        string name = "";
        string phone = "";
        while (inputFile >> value >> name >> phone)
        {

            tempStudent.id = value;
            tempStudent.name = name;
            tempStudent.phone = phone;
            students.push_back(tempStudent);
        }
    }
    else cout << "Error Opening StudentInfo.txt.. Try again." << endl;

    displayOne(students, 12546);
    displayOne(students, 15667);
    displayOne(students, 14388);

    inputFile.close();
    inputFile2.close();

//displayOne(15667);

//displayAll();

    return 0;

}

// Function definitions
void displayOne(vector<Person> students, int verifyID)
{
    bool foundID = false;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    {
        if (students[i].id == verifyID)
        {
            foundID = true;
            index = i;
        }

    }
    if (students[index].id == verifyID)
    {
        cout << "Student ID: " << students[index].id << " ";
        cout << "Student Name: " << students[index].name << " ";
        cout << "Student Phone: " << students[index].phone << " ";
        cout << "=================================";
        cout << endl;
        cout << students[index].grades[].course << endl;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to call a function that lets me cout << students[0] - number of students but also display each class they take and the scores they achieved and so forth.

Comment: And what's the current problem? Also you are copying the vector in `displayOne`.

Comment: I need to know how to store the values into the vector<Scores> grades array.

Comment: I must be missing something - what's wrong with something like students[i].grades.push_back()?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have to use `id` to map students to scores like an SQL join.

As you loop through *StudentScores.txt* and read each score into a temporary `Scores` you will have to find the `student` in `students` that matches `Scores::id`. Once you have found this student, you can `push_back` the temporary score.

Something like

```
Scores tempscore;
while (inputFile2 >> tempscore) // requires a >> overload for Scores, but here I'm 
                                // just using it as shorthand for "read in a Scores." 
                                // Strongly consider the >> overload though.
{
    auto & id = tempscore.id; // make this c++11 proof. C++11 doesn't handle 
                              // capturing  members 
    // find student who matches id
    auto found = std::find_if(students.begin(), 
                              students.end(), 
                              [id] (const Student& s) { return s.id == id; })
    if (found != students.end()) // actually found a match
    { 
        found->grades.push_back(tempscore); // add score
    }
    else
    {
        // handle missing student. Log it and discard? Abort? Your call.
    }
}
```

[Documentation for `std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

`[id] (const Student& s) { return s.id == id; }` [is a Lambda Expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). It provides a quick and dirty function to be called by `find_if` to test if it found.

You may find [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) more helpful in storing the `students` than a `std::vector`. `std::map<id, Person> students;` makes the look-up as simple as

```
Scores tempscore;
while (inputFile2 >> tempscore)
{
    // find student who matches id
    try
    {
        students.at(tempscore.id).grades.push_back(tempscore); // add score
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range &)
    {
        // handle missing student. 
    }
}
```

`std::map` is great for simple searches, but not nearly as good at iteration as `std::vector` and has a lot more overhead which can exceed the savings for searching in short lists. If the the list of students is long and program does a lot of searching for `id`s, use `map`. If it does a lot of scanning the whole list, you're probably better off with the `vector`.